# custom uitableview like uitextview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextview

I want to create a custom table view.

In the table view the user should enter the username and password and other fields.In other words the table view should behave like a uitextview. I couldnt find a good tutorial for achieving the functionality i require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a UITableViewCell with UITextView

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) 
{
    // Initialization code

      UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
      textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
      //textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
      textView.text = content;
      textview.delegate = self;
      [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, textView.contentSize.height)];
      [self addSubview:textView];
}
     return self;
}
```

don't forget to resign the keyboard.

**textViewDidEndEditing:**